# Importing Text File into MS Excel or SQL Server CE database

Tags: excel, import, sql-server-ce, text-files, notepad

I have a text file... `Something.txt`

The contents is:

```
1 ABC some_long_sentence
2 DEF another_long_sentence
3 DFG this_is_another_long sentence
```

I want to import this file.... first and second word can be separated by a space as delimiter, second and third can be separated by a space as delimiter... However the rest of them is a sentence , should be imported into a database cell.. so, the last separator would be a carriage return. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what you are asking, to get your text document into separate cells in Excel, import the data and then use the text to columns feature with space as the delimeter.

Does this help?

Comment: yes.. thanks... I was able to do tat using Excel's import text file utility.... I imported the Text file to Excel... then using SDF viewer, I imported Excel to SQL CE Db... I wanted to know if there is any direct way to load txt file with delimiters into SQL CE Db...